# Physical interpretation of polymer quantization

Tags: entropy, loop-quantum-gravity

I have read a bit about [polymer quantization](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=polymer+quantization), and I want to know what this quantization means physically. I already know that it enables us to incorporate an additional length scale that solves the resolution problem (that is, to probe smaller and smaller distances, higher energy is required, which increases Schwarzschild radius).

My question is: how can one physically explain this quantization, say to a layman, without going into mathematical details. Like, in what ways is it different from the usual quantization methods?

In particular, is there an entropy related interpretation to this?